# Indexpath in tableview delegate methods having different values

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, addressbook, nsindexpath

I am trying to take contacts from my addressbook. I am displaying the data on my tableview. For that first I am setting the height of the tableviewcell.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and after that I implement

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I write the conditions and logic inside these delegate methods. But I am facing a problem where, the value of index path in both the methods are different. Due to this, while I am looping through the addressbook(inside these methods), both the delegate methods are being executed in a different order. Why is that the index path has different values in both cases

Comment: the only thing you should care about for both delegate methods is returning the correct value **according to** the given index path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is only called just before the cell comes into view

`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called for all rows when the tableview is presented to get the total height of the tableview content.

And I must also agree with @Vince comment that the only thing you should care about is that the methods are returning the correct value according to the given index path.

Normally you should load all the data needed for the tableview into, for example a `NSArray`. Then just get the correct object from that array according to the indexpath.

Comment: No, the indexpath is the location of an row in the table view. If you have 2 sections and each section has 4 rows. Then the indexpath for the first row in the first section should `{0,0}`. Thus `indexpath.section == 0` and `indexpath.row == 0`.

Comment: I am displaying indexpath.row of both the methods, in my log. But I am getting different values in both cases

Comment: And that is correct, because is asking for different rows in that table.

Comment: Yes. I just logged both indexpath.section and indexpath.row. And in
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

the section 1 is getting called first , while in
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

section 0 gets called first. Thats where I was going wrong. 
Thanks a lot for your help and your answers are really impressive.